# Error importing product csv

Tags: magento2.2.4

I exported product csv, then added prices and tried to re-import them. This is giving me an error. Per someone's suggestion I deleted the products in admin and now I can't add them back.

Here is error message:
*Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report
1. Invalid option value for attribute "design" in row(s): 654, 656
2. Attribute with code "000" is not super in row(s): 654, 656
3. Please make sure attribute "name" is not empty. in row(s): 655
4. This name is already being used for custom option. Please enter a different name. in row(s): 654, 655*

Also, trying to import unaltered export file shows the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

***Invalid option value for attribute "design" in row***

The JSON of Magento was not able to properly read the title of my products because they included double quotes. JSON uses double quotes (") to escape related values. So in my case where a product is titled 3" Binder, JSON thinks the statement ends at 3", and throws an error because Binder is not an expected value. It was fixed by changing the product title to 3 inch Binder.

***Attribute with code "000" is not super in row(s):***

Similarly the products listed with commas in the attributes caused errors because this is a csv sheet. For example I have a quantity attribute with values ranging from 25 to 10,000. Every value with a comma caused an error (such as 1,000 2,500 and 5,000) changing them to 1000 2500 and 5000 fixed this error.